# css anchor images height issue

Tags: css, image, height, anchor

fiddle should explain the issue, but cannot see what I’m doing wrong here

here is the code:

```
body {
    background-color: #ededed;
}
#social{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;  
    left: 50px;

    border: thin solid #ff6600;
}
#social .facebook a {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px !important;
    background-color: #000000;

    border: thin solid #00ff00;
} 
#social .facebook a:hover {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px !important;
    background-color: #3B5998; 
}
<style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="social">
<div class="facebook">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="http://poststudio.co.uk/louisbrennan/facebook.png" 
    width="60" height="60"/>
    </a>  
</div>

</div>    
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/misemefein/McmAQ/

any thoughts appreciated

Comment: it would be easier if you told us your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: block;` to `#social .facebook a` so that it occupies the full height of its container

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/McmAQ/4/